# Auto-suggests upon entering character(s) into an input field?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

There is a HUGE database of cities and other stuff in the system (locations) waiting to be driven out as a drop down list, div(s) or something what can compress huge amount of choices - instantly after every character of wanted location is entered into that input field.

Its similar like adding tags here when we are submitting questions. So if we enter "L" London and Lazio gonna be listed, after "La" - only Lazio will stay available.

Any steps or cool examples how to accomplish this? Tried to find something cool by myself but no luck. I'm using jquery.

Comment: I think there are several autocomplete plugins for jQuery.

Comment: You may want to ry [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be not the best sollution but it works on my site. This script implements street name auto complete, which depends on the state and city the user had entered before. This particular piece of code listens to the event "keyup". If user has entered more than one letter, the script launches ajax request in which .php script analyses the parameters we sent, makes SQL query and replies. If the user is lucky enough and he gets some suggestion for the street name he tries to find, we show him div with id=hintsTable. We also create event listener (click) for each auto complete option, in which we replace the value of input field for the one from auto complete option and hides the drop-down list.
I hope it helps.

```
$("#street input").keyup(function(){                                                    //street enter
        var input = $('#street input').val(); //we get what user has already entered
        var code = $('#mregionSelect').val(); //city id
        if(input.length > 1)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type        : "POST",
                url         : "components/com_areas/ajaxhelper.php",
                data        : "input=" + encodeURIComponent(input) + "&code=" + code,
                cache       : false,
            }).done(function(msg){
                if(msg.length > 0)
                {
                    $('#hintsTable').html(msg); //fill drop-down list with auto complete options
                    $('#hints').css('display', 'block'); //show the list
                    $('#hintsTable tr').click(function(){
                        var hint = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                        $('#street input').val(hint);
                        $('#hints').css("display", "none");
                    })
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#hintsTable').html('');
                    $('#hints').css('display', 'none');
                    //$('#findButton').css('display', 'none');
                }
            })
        }
        else
        {
            $('#hintsTable').html('');
            $('#hints').css('display', 'none');
            //$('#findButton').css('display', 'none');
        }               
    })
```

Comment: I was using that "keyup" in a different manner (to call a PHP execution file) and it works like a charm! Thx Sergei :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a textbox with a div under

```
<input name="txtSearch" type="text" onkeydown="jscriptfunc();" autocomplete="off"/>    
<div class="autoDiv"></div> (could use CSS to format the div accordingly)
```

Now the jscriptfunc for when the user presses a key down could be coded to call a PHP script with the help of ajax. This PHP script is taking whatever the user typed thus far and performing a simple pattern match search e.g.

```
Select * from table where field like '$input%' limit 5;
```

Then we just take the result and feed it into the div